# magick.exe don´t work correctly

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, imagemagick

```
set foo=311421232322383538353247425048463555333928324647554314304128474534464839363549444437435238613561311240095442505231573523988539009812811847
magick convert -font Ciphered-Regular.ttf -pointsize 72 label:%foo%  bar_%random%.png
```

and it´s create something like (this is end of file):

```
¤x°{´TB    %”PBQcŃüĄ‰ŽťűX}Âµjß›úţĚ%‰.CwűĄďűĹĄä-ˇ„fŚ¸€notJĹ±}ÄwÄŮôbF‰·J(AĄýĺi(ü˛¦e”-•PB %”PB    %”PB    %”PB    %”PB    %”PB    %”@Ä˙¨"A;Űýż   %tEXtdate:create 2019-04-08T19:01:03+02:00 ĐÝ   %tEXtdate:modify 2019-04-08T19:01:03+02:00QŤe¨   ZzTXtlabel  ™ŚÁ 1[
QűoěČéđY% B1_úO©U>]Ú&ą5ˇWm‹ŹP“•©Đá2K­rlŃq]Đ P:g­g‡űŐ;cnŠ‰ëŕ
|Ç    IEND®B`‚
```

and textlabel is empty, but image is created corectly, but i need textlabel in file for next use in my program

this is what i need for example (for generate this is shorter message before):

```
‹ç/M´mßÓčnä"4PýţÔgţśč0x§ßűp5S(&oE4b:ČÂŤN±8!ŹÂť…lşż(.QDEQDEQDEQDEQDţiÖo¶sË]â   %tEXtdate:create 2019-04-08T18:45:32+02:00lŚŰ>   %tEXtdate:modify 2019-04-08T18:45:32+02:00Ńc‚   ltEXtlabel 311421232322383538353247425048463555333928324647554314304128474534464839363549444437435238613561311240,ě˘'    IEND®B`‚
```

for small variables work correctly too, but i generate sometimes longer number line.
I´m using Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.379], magick 7.0.8.39 win32 static portable